# mysql data fetch with codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to perform reporting from database where user will enter his own criteria to pull data,

Here is modal function of my fetch,

```
public function fetch_insight($insight_start, $insight_end, $user_id,
      $manager_id, $category_id, $expense_method, $report_status, $policy_breach)
{

  $array = array('ec_expensedetails.expense_date >'         => $insight_start,
          'ec_expensedetails.expense_date <='   => $insight_end,
          'ec_reports.report_status'            => $report_status,
          'ec_expensedetails.user_id' => $user_id,
          'ec_reports.manager_id' => $manager_id,
          'ec_expensedetails.category_id' =>  $category_id,
          'ec_expensedetails.expense_method'  =>  $expense_method,
          'ec_expensedetails.policy_breach' =>  $policy_breach);
  $this->db->where($array);

  $this->db->select('ec_expensedetails.*');
  $this->db->select('ec_expensecategory.*');
  $this->db->select('ec_reports.*');
  $this->db->select('ec_users.*');
  $this->db->from('ec_users');
  $this->db->join('ec_expensedetails', 'ec_expensedetails.user_id = '.$user_id,'INNER');
  $this->db->join('ec_expensecategory', 'ec_expensecategory.category_id = ec_expensedetails.category_id','INNER');
  $this->db->join('ec_reports', 'ec_reports.report_status = ec_reports.report_status ','INNER');
  return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Now in when user selects fields like `$user_id, $manager_id, $category_id,` it gives me result array,

Problems,

1. But example if user just want to pull data with dates without any other where conditions, how can i remove that other where conditions of user_id, manager_id, category_id?
2. report_status in JOIN is column value field, i can join tables with ID field, but how can i JOIN table with value field in codeigniter? see last join in code.

Thanks,

Comment: 1 - you can just build your `$array` array up gradually, and conditionally add each key/value depending on what you want. 2 - you just change the condition, where it says `xxxxx.category_id = yyyy.category_id` change the field to something else!

Comment: @moopet, thanks i could manage with problem-1 by using array_merge and checking input conditions, but i could not manage to join tables on fields that have no ID, but value field, actually i am talking about last join..ec_reports